# Is it practical to load user settings/preferences from an embedded database?

Tags: java, database-design, settings

The program that I am currently developing will have user preferences and I would like to ask if it would be practical to load these settings from an embedded database? Like for example if the user wants a different color scheme, the value of that certain color will be stored in the database. I am aware of read/writing files but would this idea be better?

A few examples are if the user wants the sound effects in the buttons, he can choose in the settings page and it will send the value to the database as a boolean. Then when the program is started again, it will read it from the database then apply all the user preferences in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using external files is not more complicated (with JSON or YAML or XML) than a database, with the additional property that the files can be inspected and modified by a text editor, which may be a plus or a minus (if you want to make sure the data is always correct and hence entered via your application, you may not like that). But certainly using an embedded database is doable. Files have also the advantage that they can be copied so users can share settings easily.